# My function for finding the number of standard deviations that the elements in a column vary from the mean is ignoring some rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a function in pandas that takes in a numerical column (`col`) and a Dataframe (`myDF`).
It creates a new column called 'Dev from avg' within the Data frame.
Each entry in this column is the number of standard deviations the numerical value in `col` is from the mean of `col`.

It works fine for the first bunch of rows in `col` (i.e., it is able to successfully determine the number of standard deviations for each entry). However, after a certain point, it ignores the remaining rows.

Here is my code:

```
def det_dev(col, myDF):
    avg = col.mean()
    snd = col.std()
    j = 0
    
    # Initialize this column 
    myDF['Dev From avg'] = "None"

    for i in col: 
        if (i >= avg):
            k = 1
            while (k != None):
                if (i <= (avg + (k * snd))):
                    myDF['Dev From avg'][j] = k
                    break
                k = k + 1
        elif (i < avg):
            k = -1
            while (k != None):
                if (i >= (avg + (k * snd))):
                    myDF['Dev From avg'][j] = k
                    break
                k = k - 1
        j = j + 1
```

I have spent the last 3 hours trying to understand why the function is able to compute the number of standard deviations from the mean and put it in the 'Dev From avg' column for the first couple of rows but not later on.

This is what the output looks like if I put it in a relative frequency bar graph:
[image]

As you can see, the initialized value of "None" does not get replaced by the number of standard deviations from the mean for most of the rows.

Comment: Kindly provide sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues:

- inefficiency due to row-wise operations.
- unsafe indexing, which could lead to unexpected results.

Better use a vectorized approach to calculate standard deviations from the mean:

```py
def det_dev_all_cols(df):
    for col in df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns:
        avg = df[col].mean()
        snd = df[col].std()
        df[col + ' Dev From avg'] = ((df[col] - avg) / snd).apply(round)
```

Then use it like this

```
det_dev_all_cols(df)
```

This will add a new `'Dev From avg'` column for each numeric column in the `DataFrame`, containing the number of standard deviations each entry is from the mean of its respective column, rounded to the nearest whole number.